# How can I make a snipe command that doesn't snipe cross server (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

I'm trying to create a command in python using discord.py, it's your standard snipe command but all the ways I've seen to do this online have one issue. They all have a global snipe variable, e.g if I go into server A and type "hello" then delete that message then go to server B and type the snipe command it will say that the last message was "hello". Is there a simple way to solve this issue?
Edit - got it working! *(Somehow)* thanks for anyone who helped

Comment: Probably a dict that maps guild ids to some object. Whenever you call the command, you look up `ctx.guild.id` and then act on that object instead of a global variable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a handler.

Do it like this.

```
contentguild = self.last_msg.guild
guild = ctx.guild
```

That make an if statement:

```
if contentguild.id != guild.id:
        await ctx.reply("There is no message to snipe!", 
                         mention_author=False)
        return
```

I assume you already have the snipe command set up, so with these pieces of code you should be able to get it working. If you really have problems react to this message and I can give you the whole code for the snipe command, but I would prefer that you first try it yourself. ;-)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help but I've been trying for the greater part of a day to get this working. I've tried just about everything I can think of and I still can't get it to work! Would you be able to give a little more help?

Comment: Are you using cogs?

Comment: Yes but I got it working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the one that gave you the answer? I would highly appreciate it.